# Ejecuta el constructor de la clase base habiendo llamado al constructor de la clase herencia

Tags: c#, herencia, constructor

Soy nuevo por aquí, recién estoy aprendiendo a programar y lo estoy haciendo con C#.

Mi duda es la siguiente, he creado una clase (Coche) que hereda de la clase padre (Vehículo). El problema que me está dando es que cuando llamo al constructor por defecto de la clase coche, me imprime el constructor por defecto de la clase padre. Cómo evito ésto? no encuentro la solución por ningún lado. Muchas gracias

using System;

namespace ProyectoVehiculo1
{
internal class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
        Coche Seat = new Coche(); 
        Seat.get_info();

    }

    class Vehiculo
    {

        public Vehiculo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Estamos en el constructor sin parámetros de la clase base");
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce el color del vehículo");
            this.color = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce el num de plazas del vehículo");
            this.plazas = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }


        public Vehiculo( String marca, int plazasVehiculo)
        {
            this.marca = marca;
            this.plazas = plazasVehiculo;
        }


        public virtual void get_info()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("El vehículo es de color {0} y tiene {1} plazas.", Color, Plazas);
        }

        public String Color
        {
            get { return color; }
            set { color = value; }
        }

        public String Marca
        {
            get { return marca; }
            set { marca = value; }
        }

        public int Plazas
        {
            get { return plazas; }
            set { plazas = value; }
        }

        public String Medio
        {
            get { return medio; }
            set { medio = value; }
        }


        String color;
        String marca;
        int plazas;
        string medio;


    }


    class Coche : Vehiculo
    {

        public Coche()
        {
            Medio = "terrestre";
            Console.WriteLine("Estamos en el constructor sin parámetros de la clase herencia");
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce el color del coche");
            Color = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce el num de plazas del coche");
            Plazas = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }


        public override void get_info()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El coche es de color {0} y tiene {1} plazas. Su medio es el {2}.", Color, Plazas, Medio);
        }

    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No lo evitas.. para eso heredas.. para justamente se ejecuten los dos constructores.. si no ejecutara el constructor del padre, como inicializaria sus cosas?? el tema aca, es que nunca ningun constructor deberia imprimir nada de nada en ningun lado (vale si estas aprendiendo)...

Comment: Tampoco deberias pedir cosas en el constructor.. el constructor construye la clase... pero si por ejemplo, quisieras pedir un color, este deberia llegar por parametro a la clase.. vos deberias pedirlo antes...

Comment: No uses el constructor para eso, el constructor solo debe usarse para inicializar la clase y determinados atributos de la clase, te recomiendo que crees metodos para lo que quieres hacer, en programacion todo tiene su aplicacion

Comment: Soy un constructor y me llaman, llego al lugar y no hay material, me toca hacer una llamada y pedir ladrillos, cuando llegan, resulta que no hay mezcla, vuelvo a llamar para pedirla, y resulta que me envían cemento, piedras y arena, debo mezclar yo mismo, y cuando esté todo listo recién empiezo a construir. Eso es lo que sucede en tu aplicación. El constructor necesita todo listo para entregar el objeto de la forma más expedita posible. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás viendo es totalmente correcto.

[La documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors) dice:

> In a derived class, if a base-class constructor isn't called explicitly by using the base keyword, the parameterless constructor, if there's one, is called implicitly.

En español:

> Si en una clase derivada no se llama explícitamente un constructor de la clase base, el constructor (de la clase base) sin parámetros, si existe, es llamado implícitamente.

Lo único que puedes hacer es evitar que una de las condiciones se cumpla para que el constructor base no sea llamado.

O si solo te molestan los mensajes, como se te indicó en los comentarios, no le des al constructor la responsabilidad de pedir los datos.

---

Alternativamente puedes analizar si realmente necesitas usar herencia.

A mi parecer, la clase `Coche` no difiere significativamente de la clase `Vehiculo`. No tiene variables adicionales ni funciones adicionales. Por lo que podrías usar la clase `Vehiculo` para cualquier caso.

Además todas las variabes son privadas, por lo que no se estarían heredando a las clases derivadas.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias Mateo por tu pronta respuesta. Creo que sería interesante que pudiera usarse un constructor en la clase derivada a pesar de que la clase base tenga otro con las misma características, pero habrá que adaptarse. Gracias